# Why is @auth tag in AWS AppSync resulting in unauthorized access error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have an Amplify project that I have started working on the auth for, but the @auth tag isn't working as expected. I have a cognito user pool with a Admins group, yet when I sign in as an authenticated user that is a part of the Admins group, I still get an unauthorized access error. This previously worked, then on further tests I used a vtl resolver which didn't do what I wanted, so I deleted it, then same with a lambda function (amplify add function), which I deleted (amplify remove function). After those, I went back to this solution and it didn't work. I am using this with a React frontend app hosted with amplify.

schema.graphql

```
    type Post @model @auth(
        rules: [
          { allow: groups, groups: ["Users"]}
        ]
      ) {
        id: ID! @primaryKey
        text: String
        votes: Int
    }
```

result

```
    [
        {
            "path": [
                "listPosts"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": "Unauthorized",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "sourceName": null
                 }
            ],
            "message": "Not Authorized to access listPosts on type Query"
       }
    ]
```

I've made sure that the user pool is attached to the appsync project, tried replacing "Admins" with other groups (such as "Users", then made a new cognito user attached to that group, same result as above), nothing has worked to restore the functionality I had before (which was that it worked as expected)